# Android Security for data transfer to web service?

Tags: android, android-widget

i need to send some 3rd party api username and password to the web service.I need to provide high security for that username and password. In what way i can provide such high level security , whether i have to use and certificate or encoding format?

if need to any certificate or other class please help me out and provide some sample if you have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self signed certificate to send data through ssl, ssl implementation can change according to your server and operating system implementations, google will help you. You can use open-ssl to self sign your certificate. Afterwards you can get data through a secure connection.

Then in android you can accept all kind of certificates

http://yekmer.posterous.com/how-to-accept-self-signed-certificates-in-and

or just one certificate(this is more secure if you will not change the certificate any more)

http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

You can just send and get data by using https with the help of these blog posts. Then your connection will become secure to man in the middle attacks.